# I am not able to record login page events in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When I start my proxy server, set my browser settings to local host with specified port, and enter the URL, the first event is recorded.
Then I go for login credentials, which is not being recorder.
Can some one provide me some detailed help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to record the login with a different browser, after you start the proxy server.  If that does not work then use the option in jmeter to record all embedded objects in page, as well as using the transaction grouping option.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not jmeter user, so this is technically a guess based on my Selenium experience:

While Selenium has issues with HTTP Basic authentification, my guess is, that Jmeter will also have issues with that and I guess, that the page you try to reach is HTTP Basic auth protected site.

(Too much guessing, I know)

So, my advice is try to pass username and password in the URL request like this

```
http://username:password@example.com
```

But this applies only if my guessing was right...